# What's wrong or missing in Struts 2 jQuery tag?

Tags: jquery, struts2, struts2-jquery

**Now I'm start learning Struts 2 jQuery sj: tag. Below code is copied from website.**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s"%>
    <%@ taglib uri="/struts-jquery-tags" prefix="sj"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <s:form action="sample" theme="bootstrap" cssClass="form-horizontal" label="Form with jQuery UI Elements">
            <sj:datepicker id="datepicker" parentTheme="bootstrap" label="Datepicker" tooltip="Tooltip for Datepicker"/>
            <s:url id="language_url" action="languages" />
            <sj:autocompleter id="autocompleter" parentTheme="bootstrap" label="Autocompleter" tooltip="Tooltip for Autocompleter" href="%{languages_url}" loadMinimumCount="1"/>
          </s:form>
    </body> 
    </html>
```

**This error occur please advice me I'm beginner in struts 2 jQuery**

```
HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Template /template/bootstrap/form-close.ftl not found. - Class: freemarker.template.Configuration
File: Configuration.java
Method: getTemplate
Line: 580 - freemarker/template/Configuration.java:580:-1
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:413)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:326)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:253)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:88)

root cause

Template /template/bootstrap/form-close.ftl not found. - Class: freemarker.template.Configuration
File: Configuration.java
Method: getTemplate
Line: 580 - freemarker/template/Configuration.java:580:-1
    org.apache.struts2.components.UIBean.end(UIBean.java:515)
    org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.ComponentTagSupport.doEndTag(ComponentTagSupport.java:42)
    org.apache.jsp.pages.samplePage1_jsp._jspx_meth_s_005fform_005f0(samplePage1_jsp.java:262)
    org.apache.jsp.pages.samplePage1_jsp._jspService(samplePage1_jsp.java:104)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:326)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:253)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:88)

root cause

java.io.FileNotFoundException: Template /template/bootstrap/form-close.ftl not found.
    freemarker.template.Configuration.getTemplate(Configuration.java:580)
    freemarker.template.Configuration.getTemplate(Configuration.java:543)
    org.apache.struts2.components.template.FreemarkerTemplateEngine.renderTemplate(FreemarkerTemplateEngine.java:96)
    org.apache.struts2.components.UIBean.mergeTemplate(UIBean.java:559)
    org.apache.struts2.components.UIBean.end(UIBean.java:513)
    org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.ComponentTagSupport.doEndTag(ComponentTagSupport.java:42)
    org.apache.jsp.pages.samplePage1_jsp._jspx_meth_s_005fform_005f0(samplePage1_jsp.java:262)
    org.apache.jsp.pages.samplePage1_jsp._jspService(samplePage1_jsp.java:104)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:326)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:253)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:88)*
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not able to find bootstrap theme files. Try using some other theme like xhtml, or css_xhtml. It will run your code. Also remove that parent theme attribute from everywhere. Try running the simplest code. U may try the complex one once this is clear.